# How many 5-digit numbers are there such that digits $1,2,3$ appear at least once?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many five digit numbers there are such that digits $1, 2, 3$
>   appear at least once?

I prefer a direct approach rather than applying the inclusion-exclusion principle.

I tried: $3!(9\cdot 4\cdot 9\cdot 5+3\cdot 4+3\cdot 9\cdot 5)=10602$?

Comment: That's only the start of it, of course. @graydad

Comment: @graydad: No, not good. If I do it like that I need to consider if only (2,3) appear, then if only (1,3) appear, then if only (1,2) appear, then if only 1 appear, etc.

Comment: Ultimately, this is an inclusion-exclusion question.

Comment: Direct method is better.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Please help

Comment: @ThomasAndrews right, but I'm hoping that helps lead user45220 to an answer

Comment: @user45220 If you know the better method, why don't you use it and come up with something you tried?

Comment: @AlexR: I tried. $3!(9*4*9*5+3*4+3*9*5)=10602$?

Comment: @user45220 Please put this into the question, ideally using `\cdot` for the multiplications and explain where each factor comes from.

Comment: @AlexR: sorry, I'll do now.

Comment: @AlexR: I tried. I cannot explain it, sorry.

Comment: @user45220 I'm writing up a rather long-ish answer just so you see what you need to think about when using a direct counting approach.

Comment: @Jack it can be a good idea to edit in context, but it should not be rather counter to what OP says.

Answer (score 3):

We have $6\cdot 7^4$ numbers in which the digits $1,2,3$ do not appear, $7\cdot 8^4$ numbers in which the digits $1,2$ do not appear, $8\cdot 9^{4}$ numbers in which the digit $1$ does not appear, hence by the inclusion-exclusion principle the answer is given by:

$$9\cdot 10^4-3\cdot 8\cdot 9^4+3\cdot 7\cdot 8^4-6\cdot 7^4 = \color{red}{4146}.$$

Answer (score 0):

As requested, a direct approach.
Note that this is not even remotely elegant and a lot more work (compared to the inclusion-exclusion principle you can see in Jack's answer).

**Subdivision**
The Numbers can be split (disjunctively) into the following categories:

1. Exactly one $1,2,3$ appear (e.g. $12300$)
2. Two of one digit appears and one of each of the other digits (e.g. $11230$)
3. Two of two digits appear and one of the third (e.g. $11223$)
4. Three of one digit and one of each of the other digits (e.g. $11123$)

Each can be subcategorized as follows: 1. has no subcategories, 2. leaves the choice of the double number (factor $3$), 3. leaves the choice of the single number (factor $3$), four leaves the choice of the triple number (factor $3$). So

$$N = C_1 + 3C_2 + 3C_3 + 3C_4$$

Where we count a subcategory for each.

**Counting $C_1$**
We chose where the numbers go ($\binom53 = 10$) and in what order they are ($3! = 6$). Then we chose the remaining digits ($7^2 = 49$).
$$C_1 = \binom53\cdot 3!\cdot 7^2 = 2940$$

**Counting $C_1$ without leading $0$**
We must build subcategories: $1$ to $3$ in the front gives $\binom42 \cdot 3! \cdot 7^2 = 1764$ and not in the front gives $\binom43 \cdot 3! \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 1008$ for a total of
$$C_1' = 2772$$

**Counting $C_2$**
We chose the positions ($\binom54 = 5$) and their order ($\frac{4!}{2!} = 12$). Then we chose the remaining digit ($7$)
$$C_2 = \binom54\cdot \frac{4!}{2!}\cdot 7 = 420$$

**Counting $C_2$ without leading $0$**
Similar to category 1, the subdivision yields $\binom43 \cdot \frac{4!}{2!} \cdot 7 = 336$ and $1\cdot \frac{4!}{2!} \cdot 6 = 72$ for a total of
$$C_2' = 408$$

**Counting $C_3$**
We chose the order only
$$C_3 = \frac{5!}{2!2!} = 30$$

**Counting $C_4$**
We chose the position of the three digits ($\binom53 = 10$) and the order of the remaining two ($2!=2$)
$$C_4 = \binom53 \cdot 2! = 20$$

**Summing it all**
Using the formula above we get
$$N = 2940 + 3\cdot 420 + 3 \cdot 30 + 3 \cdot 20 = 4350$$
Or without leading $0$
$$N' = 2772 + 3\cdot 408+ 3\cdot 30 + 3 \cdot 20 = 4146$$

Comment: Have you accounted the fact that the first digit cannot be zero?

Comment: @JordanGlen No it's not. With Jack's additional requirement the answer is 4146.

Comment: @JordanGlen I've extended my answer to include both counts while retaining the direct approach.

Comment: Nicely done, @AlexR